# WebApp sees SQL DB on Virtual PC, but Console App does not

Tags: .net, sql, virtual

I'm developing a group of web applications against a SQL db, and some console apps for fiddling with data a bit. My production server and dev server are both Server2008 32bit, the differences being the dev server is on a Virtual PC and running SqlExpress 2008.

The web app and console app in question at the moment share the same connection settings. When the settings are pointed to production, both web and console app work fine. When pointed at dev, the web app does fine, but the console app can't connect(error:40, below). What difference between the two would cause this behavior?

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a 
>       connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. 
>       Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured 
>       to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - 
>       Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Virtual PC is networked via Microsoft Loopback Connection. Same behavior when I switch to an ethernet connection.

PortQry on both looks similar:

Dev:

> UDP port 1434 (ms-sql-m service): LISTENING or FILTERED
>
> Sending SQL Server query to UDP port 1434...
>
> Server's response:
>
> ServerName DEV
>   InstanceName SQLEXPRESS
>   IsClustered No
>   Version 10.50.1600.1
>   tcp 49282
>   np \DEV\pipe\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS\sql\query
>
> ==== End of SQL Server query response ====
>
> UDP port 1434 is LISTENING

Production:

> UDP port 1434 (ms-sql-m service): LISTENING or FILTERED
>
> Sending SQL Server query to UDP port 1434...
>
> Server's response:
>
> ServerName PRODUCTION
>   InstanceName MSSQLSERVER
>   IsClustered No
>   Version 9.00.4035.00
>   tcp 1433
>   np \PRODUCTION\pipe\sql\query
>
> ==== End of SQL Server query response ====
>
> UDP port 1434 is LISTENING

Connection strings as requested:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ProductionConnection" connectionString="Data Source=production.productiondomain.local;Initial Catalog=XXXXXXX;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="DevConnection" connectionString="Data Source=dev\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=XXXXXXX;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Can you post your connection string and replace sensitive information with some masking character? The possible difference is the user account privileges and how they vary from environment to environment.

Answer (score 0):

In the virtual PC where you installed SqlServer Express 2008 check if there is a group name similar to this: 'SQLServer2005MSSQLUser$PIETRO$SQLEXPRESS'.

Go into the 'Local Users and Groups' in the Computer Management of that virtual pc.

The description of the group will read something like "Members in the group have the required access and privileges to be assigned as the log on account for the associated instance of SQL Server and SQL Server FullText Search in SQL Server 2005."

To be able to connect to my local SQL Express 2005 in my notebook, I had to add the Windows account I use to logon to this notebook to that mentioned windows group. And I had to use this connection string:

```
"Data Source=PIETRO\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=irisdb;Integrated Security=True;"
```

It is important to note the 'Integrated Security=True' part. Which means, SQL Express will authenticate my connection attempt by using my windows account.

If you are not using integrated security in your connection string then you are using SQLServer authentication, and that means the user id and password in your connection string has to be a valid SQL Server login:

```
User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxx
```

I remember it was a hassle to create logins in SQL Express because SQL Express 2005 does not come with the management tool to do so but, if you have it, double check the values for user id and password you are using in your connection string for Dev is a valid login in your SqlExpress 2008.

My guess about why the web app connects to DEV Sql Express is that the web app is very likely running under the context of the ASP.NET machine account, and somehow your DEV SQL Express 2008 is authenticating that account successfully.

In summary....

If you are using integrated security, specify it in your connection string and add the windows account under which your console app runs to the sql express group in the virtual pc.

If you are using sql server authentication, then the user id and password in your connection string must be a valid sql express login.

Good luck!